# Prove solution for boundary value problem

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $h \in C[0,1]$ be a function. Show that the boundary value problem

$$u''(x) = h(x)\mbox{ on } [0,1], u(0) = 0, u(1)=0$$

has a unique solution given by

$$u(x)=\int_0^1 g(x,\xi)h(\xi)d\xi$$

with $g(x,\xi)=\cases{\xi(x-1) & if $0\le \xi\le x \le 1$\\ x(\xi-1) & if $0\le x \le \xi \le 1$}$

To show that this is a solution, one can use substitution into the BVP above.

But $$u''(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x,\xi)h(\xi)d\xi$$
and
$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x,\xi)=0$$

So $u''(x) =$ constant.

I doubt this is the way it should be. I'm really puzzled. How does one approach this problem?

Comment: Assume there are two solutions, $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$, and look at the difference $v = u_{1} - u_{2}$. To find the unique solution itself, use [Greens functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function).

Comment: you might be able to show that $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(x,\xi)=\delta(x-\xi)$ the first derivative is clearly discontinuous at $x=\xi$

Comment: @WW1 Can you please clarify what is $\delta(x-\xi)$?

Comment: This $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution, which is closely related to the whole idea behind Green's functions. Intuitively it says that for fixed $\xi$, as x passes left to right through $\xi$, $g_x$ jumps up by 1, which is why g is not just a linear function of x at fixed $\xi$.

Comment: @Ian Prof said this problem can be approached without knowledge about Green's functions. Moreover, even though $g$ is discontinuous, its derivative appears to be $0$ on the entire interval. That is, $g$ is a piecewise function of polynomials of degree 1. Thus the second derivative of g w.r.t. x must be 0.

Comment: That's not quite true. $\partial^2 g/\partial x^2$ is undefined at $x=\xi$, so it's not identically $0$

Comment: @Dylan Can you please explain why is it undefined at $x=\xi$?

Comment: The first derivative is discontinuous at $x=\xi$

Comment: $$  \frac{dg}{dx}(x,\xi)=\cases{\xi & if $0\le \xi\le x \le 1$\\ \xi-1 & if $0\le x \le \xi \le 1$}  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating piecewise, we get
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \xi && 0 \le \xi < x \\ \xi-1 && x < \xi \le 1 \end{matrix} \right. $$

Thus 
$$ u'(x) = \int_0^x \xi h(\xi) d\xi + \int_x^1 (\xi-1)h(\xi)d\xi $$

Therefore
$$ u''(x) = xh(x) - (x-1)h(x) = h(x) $$

The boundary conditions are also satisfied since $g(0,\xi)=g(1,\xi)=0$

Comment: Can you please clarify why is your first derivative of $g$ w.r.t. $x$ defined with strict inequalities instead of the non-strict ones given in the question? Also, why can't we take the 2nd derivative piecewise, as we did with taking the first derivative?
What about $g(0,0)$, is $g$ is discontinuous at $\xi = 0$, as per the piecewise definition in the question?
And how do we know that this solution is unique?

Comment: @sequence You can take the second derivative piecewise away from $x=\xi$ (and you get zero out there). But at $x=\xi$ the first derivative is already *discontinuous* so there is no hope of differentiating it in the usual sense. Also, I'm not sure that this simple construction already furnishes uniqueness. Usually uniqueness for BVPs requires some traditional PDE analysis; for example in this problem you can get it from the Lax-Milgram theorem.

Comment: @sequence I made a few edits. The strict inequality has to remain because the second derivative doesn't exist at $x=\xi$. If you differentiate piecewise again:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial^2 x} = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 && 0 \le x < \xi \\ \textrm{undefined} && x = \xi \\ 0 && x < \xi \le 1 \end{matrix} \right.$$

An alternate notation would be $ \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial^2 x} = \delta(x-\xi) $, but knowledge of the Dirac-Delta isn't necessary for the problem